# How to get the name of the currently active sheet in Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I understand calling `wb.sheetnames` returns a list of the names as strings for each sheet, however I cannot see a way to get the name of the currently active sheet. There seems to be no named attribute in the [worksheet module](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html) to reference.

As a basic example, I want to write the name of the sheet into cell `A1`, for each sheet that is inside the workbook;

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
for sheet in wb.sheetnames:
    ws.insert_rows(1)
    ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = sheet.name << Can I reference the active sheetname here with something similar?
```

Or will it require utilizing the `wb.sheetnames` method and iterating through each as such;

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
    names = [sheet for sheet in wb.sheetnames]
    i = 0
    for sheet in wb.sheetnames:
        ws.insert_rows(1)
        ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = names[i]
        i += 1
```

Comment: the workbook instance (wb) has a get_active_sheet() method...you can use that to get the active worksheet name

Comment: Thanks Sarthak, add as an answer

Comment: Why do you expect the worksheet to know this? It's a documented workbook property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the workbook instance (wb) has the `active` property...you can use that to get the active worksheet

Answer (score 6):

I explored the source code for `openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.__init__.py`
You can see it has the `title` attribute.

For example to get the name of active worksheet you have to do this:

```
>>> sheet = workbook.active
>>> sheet.title
"sheet 1"
```

- Where "sheet 1" is the name of the active sheet.